# How to extract dynamically data from another database in function with DBName as parameter?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, functions, exec

I have one main database (`MAIN`) and several client DBs (`CLIENTDB`). I need to start query in `MAIN` and to get data from `CLIENTDB`. The client DB can be found also on linked server. My problem is that I need to do this in a function with `EXEC`, so I can get `SELECT * FROM SRV.CLIENTDB`, but this in not allowed by SQL Server. Is there another way to do that?

I need to have code like inside the function:

```
DECLARE @sSRV AS VARCHAR(128) = 'SRV';
DECLARE @sDB AS VARCHAR(128) = 'CLIENTDB1';

EXEC('SELECT * FROM ' + sSRV + '.' + @sDB + '.MyTable');
```

I need a function, because I need to make joins with it inside my engine.

Comment: Does it not work if you use the fully qualified name (linked server), e.g. select * from server.database.schema.table? Also try this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/

Comment: This is the problem - I need fully qualified name as parameter.

Comment: Use synonyms in your main db and send a db name parameter to your function. And depending on the value of the parameter use a CASE/IF to get data from the corresponding client db.

Comment: I thought about this @Marian, but there are 2 problems: 1st the count of client DBs can increase to several hundreds and more and I also need to change the code of the engine each time a new DB is introduced :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this dynamically via `EXEC`, as IIRC you can't do that in a function. You can't use an ad-hoc distributed query via `OPENROWSET` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx) either as `OPENROWSET` explicitly requires its inputs including the query text to be string *literals* not more general string *values* (so you can't use an expression or variable).

The only ways I can think of involve either having one function per remote database or the `CASE/IF` suggestion from Marian's comment. You could pragmatically create such a function by cursoring through a view based in `sys.servers` and other DMVs to put the function together through string concatenation, then replace the old version with the new using a call to `EXEC`. You still need to run the generation procedure every time the list of linked servers changes, but at least it would just be one procedure call (or script/statement run) and not a more manual code change.

This all sounds *very* hacky though. Such a "code smell" would suggest a redesign is in order if you have such power!

Comment: 10x, @DavidSpillett. I have same way of thoughts, but I hoped that I'd missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post answers the question well. Using

```
EXEC AT
```

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/

Here's a portion of the post:

```
--Script 1 : Create a linked server 
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'FARAWAYSERVER', 'SQL Server'
--Script 2 : Execute a simple SELECT statement on the linked server
EXEC ('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM AdventureWorksLT.SalesLT.Customer') AT                                  
[FARAWAYSERVER];
GO
--Script 3 : Executing multiple SELECT statements on linked server and     
--getting multiple resultsets
EXEC ('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM AdventureWorksLT.SalesLT.Customer;
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM AdventureWorksLT.SalesLT.CustomerAddress;') AT    
[FARAWAYSERVER];
GO
```

Thanks,

Comment: I need to make `JOIN` with result of the select, can you add code to show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Given this requirement:

> I need a function, because I need to make joins with it inside my engine.

I would say that the requirement itself (that it needs to be a function) is misplaced given the stated goal (that the data needs to be joined with local tables and/or views). The issue is that TVFs (whether they be T-SQL or SQLCLR) behave in such a manner as to not be conducive to being joined. They:

1. have a fixed estimated row count that could throw the optimizer off (T-SQL multi-statement TVF = 1 row, SQLCLR TVF = 1000 rows), and
2. do not have any statistics on their columns.

For these two reasons, it is often best to dump the results to a local temporary table and then JOIN to that. So, you could accomplish this easily enough by doing the following:

1. Create a stored procedure that:

   1. cycles through your list of servers and databases
   2. constructs a dynamic SQL string in your desired form of `'SELECT * FROM ' + sSRV + '.' + @sDB + '.MyTable'` (of course, including a schema name before the table name ;-)
   3. executes that dynamic SQL
2. in the main stored procedure:

   1. create a local temporary table to hold the results from the new stored procedure
   2. `INSERT INTO #LocalTempTable (column_list) EXEC dbo.NewStoredProcedure;`
   3. *optionally* add indexes to #LocalTempTable
   4. Add joins to #LocalTempTable

This will get you what you want in a way that will perform better than the initial request, while also allowing for the list of servers and databases to fluctuate over time.